# Python: Capturing double backslash C char with regex

Tags: python, c, regex, backslash

I'm attempting to capture `'\\'` with Python regex via the re module.  I have attempted to do this using:

```
back = re.compile(r"'\\'")
print back.findall(line)
```

Where `line` is: `char = '\\';`

But this doesn't capture anything.

I also tried:

```
 back = re.compile("'\\\\'")
 print back.findall(line)
```

To no avail.  What's wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
back = re.compile(r"'\\\\'")
```

**Code:**

```
>>> back = re.compile(r"'\\\\'")
>>> line = r"char = '\\';"
>>> print back.findall(line)
["'\\\\'"]
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.  I'll accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Well, the real answer is that you have used raw strings. You could also use `"'\\\\\\\\"'`, because the backslash is the escape character of both Python strings and the regular expressions.

Comment: Yes that is true. OP also used raw string in `back = re.compile(r"'\\'")` but that will match a single backslash only.